# creating form from infopath template

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, sharepoint-2010, infopath2010

I have created the xml file (infopath form) from the template(xsn) programatically.
I have the following xml file structure from the template file(xsn).  Now I want to append values to the xml file.

```
   <my:PropertyDetails>
    <my:AddressSelectionList>2201.00000000000</my:AddressSelectionList>
    <my:PropRef>210</my:PropRef>
    <my:UPRN>2201.00000000000</my:UPRN>
    <my:AddressLine>220 test road</my:AddressLine>
    <my:PropId>210</my:PropId>
    <my:BlockUPRN></my:BlockUPRN>
    <my:Attachments xsi:nil="true"></my:Attachments>
    <my:Filegroup>
      <my:URL></my:URL>
      <my:URLText></my:URLText>
    </my:Filegroup>
  </my:PropertyDetails>
  <my:ScaffoldMeasure>
    <my:groupRepeat>
      <my:Description></my:Description>
      <my:Code></my:Code>
      <my:Unit></my:Unit>
      <my:Rate xsi:nil="true"></my:Rate>
      <my:Quantity></my:Quantity>
      <my:Cost xsi:nil="true"></my:Cost>
      <my:Comments></my:Comments>
      <my:ID></my:ID>
      <my:Title></my:Title>
    </my:groupRepeat>
  </my:ScaffoldMeasure>
<my:PorchBalcony>
    <my:groupRepeat>
      <my:Description></my:Description>
      <my:Code></my:Code>
      <my:Unit></my:Unit>
      <my:Rate xsi:nil="true"></my:Rate>
      <my:Quantity></my:Quantity>
      <my:Cost xsi:nil="true"></my:Cost>
      <my:Comments></my:Comments>
      <my:ID></my:ID>
      <my:Title></my:Title>
    </my:groupRepeat>
  </my:PorchBalcony>
```

I am trying to access as follows:

```
> XmlNodeList properNodeList =
> xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("my:PropertyDetails");
> XmlNodeList smNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("my:ScaffoldMeasure");

var a=  new XElement(
                myns + "groupRepeat",
                from c in xmlDoc.Elements(nsm + "ScaffoldMeasure") select 
                new XElement(nsm + "groupRepeat",
       new XElement(nsm + "Description", "scaffold1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "Code", "sc1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "Unit", "sc1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "Rate", "sc1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "Quantity", "sc1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "Cost", "sc1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "Comments", "sc1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "ID", "sc1"),
                new XElement(nsm + "Title", "ssssssss")));         
       xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\ttt.xml");
```

Now I need to append the values in the groupRepeat section. Can anybody suggest whats the best way to append values to the  section?
Thanks

Comment: What type is `xmlDoc` in your code, `XDocument` or `XmlDocument`?

Comment: It is   XDocument,   XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\1.xml");

Comment: is `<my:ScaffoldMeasure>` root node of your XML?

Comment: updated the questions part, have given the structure of xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after several clarifications I asked in comment, I'm still not sure what you are after *exactly*. How about this :

```
.....
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

var sm = xmlDoc.Descendants(nsm + "ScaffoldMeasure").First();
var groupRepeat = new XElement(nsm + "groupRepeat",
                       new XElement(nsm + "Description", "scaffold1"),
                       new XElement(nsm + "Code", "sc1"),
                       new XElement(nsm + "Unit", "sc1"),
                       new XElement(nsm + "Rate", "sc1", 
                                        new XAttribute(xsi + "nil", true)),
                       new XElement(nsm + "Quantity", "sc1"),
                       new XElement(nsm + "Cost", "sc1", 
                                        new XAttribute(xsi + "nil", true)),
                       new XElement(nsm + "Comments", "sc1"),
                       new XElement(nsm + "ID", "sc1"),
                       new XElement(nsm + "Title", "ssssssss"));
sm.Add(groupRepeat);
xmlDoc.Save(@"C:\ttt.xml");
```

I assumed you have exactly one `<my:ScaffoldMeasure>` node in the XML and you want to add another `<my:groupRepeat>` node completed with child nodes within that `<my:ScaffoldMeasure>`.

Comment: thanks so much.The above code worked for me.. This is what exactly wanted as I was not getting the right syntax.